# Number is not incrementing by 1 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this code where if the opacity is less than or equal to 0, the message number is suppose to go up by 1, but when I run the code, the message number increases by 77 or 152 or 66, etc. Could you help me?
My code:

```js
//variables
var x = 0;
var opacity = 0;
var messageNumber = 0;
var talk1 = ["hello", "welcome to idle ball", "potato"];
var lol = 1;


//set opacity to 1
function opacitySet1(speed) {
  document.getElementById("talk").style.opacity = opacity;
  opacity += speed;
}

//set opacity to 0
function opacitySet0(speed) {
  document.getElementById("talk").style.opacity = opacity;
  opacity -= speed;
}


function IntervalManager(flag, animate, time, para1) {
  if (flag) {
    var intervalSet = setTimeout(animate, time, para1)
  }
}


function IntervalManagerII(flag, animate, time, para1) {
  if (flag) {
    var intervalSetII = setTimeout(animate, time, para1)
  }
}

//to delay time
function nothing() {}


function message(startPart) {
  document.getElementById("talk").innerHTML = messageNumber;
  if (opacity >= 0 && lol == 0) {
    setTimeout(nothing, 1);
    IntervalManagerII(true, opacitySet0, 300, 0.005);
    IntervalManager(false)
  }
  if (opacity <= 1 && lol == 1) {
    IntervalManager(true, opacitySet1, 300, 0.005);
    IntervalManagerII(false)
  }
  if (opacity <= 0) {
    lol = 1;
    IntervalManagerII(false);
    messageNumber += 1;
  } //this is the part that is not working
  if (opacity >= 1) {
    lol = 0;
    IntervalManager(false);
  }
};

setInterval(function() {
  message(0)
});
```

Comment: because you don't reach that code, you call IntervalManagerII and don't return from that

Comment: maybe try to set a delay to setInterval or it will be fired as fast as possible

Answer (score 0):

**New answer**

After discussing in the comments, it turns out you think JavaScript timers are blocking the execution of the main thread. It does not work this way. Consider the following example (`2` is printed almost instantly, and `1` is printed after one second).

```
> | setTimeout(function(){console.log(1)}, 1000);
  | setTimeout(function(){console.log(2)}, 0);
< | ...
  | 2
  | 1
```

Also read [this article](https://johnresig.com/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) from jQuery's creator.

Since your code is based on a wrong assumption, I think it makes no sense to work on your question any longer.

---

**Old answer**

Your `setInterval` timer is running a lot faster than your `setTimeout` timers, meaning that it queues a lot of `setTimeout` timers before starting to increment the opacity. During this time, the message is incremented and printed at interval max speed. After a couple of ms, all `setTimeout` timers start firing one after the other with almost no delay between them, and interleaving with `setInterval` timers, which leads to an (almost) unpredictable mess.